# How can I use constructor injection for ViewModel with Dagger2 android?

Tags: android-studio, mvvm, dependency-injection, dagger, android-viewmodel

I want to use ViewModel with Dagger2 but I don't know how to use constructor injection with ViewModelProviders or ViewModelProvider.Factory

How can I use ViewModel with constructor injection? Should I use ViewModelProvider.Factory or ViewModelProviders?

**Update:**
You can find the solution with details in [this link](https://azabost.com/injectable-android-viewmodels/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own custom class extending `ViewModelProvider.Factory`

```
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
private val providers: @JvmSuppressWildcards Map<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    var provider = providers[modelClass]
    if (provider == null) {
        for ((key, value) in providers) {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(key)) {
                provider = value
                break
            }
        }
    }
    if (provider == null) {
        throw IllegalStateException("unknown model class $modelClass")
    }

    return provider.get() as T
  }
}
```

Create module for this class and inject the module in your `ApplicationComponent` class

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelFactoryModule {
   @Binds
   abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory
}
```

Then inside your fragment inject this factory

```
@Inject
lateinit var factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
```

and initialize your viewModel like this

```
val vm: YourViewModel by viewModels { factory }
```

Comment: I want to use just one factory for all ViewModels in my project. But in using ViewModelProvider.Factory We can use just specific constructors.